# Convert objects to short lines

Tags: inkscape

I am new in Inkscape.
I need to know how convert objects (any: lines, cyrcles, free drawn by pen, ets) to object consists from small lines (1.5 - 2 mm (need to specify)).
Please look to example on the picture.

[image: Exanple]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this in a few steps:

1. If not a path already, convert the object to a path (*Path -> Convert to path*).
2. Add nodes to your path with *Extensions -> Modify Path -> Add Nodes* ([doc here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-ModifyPath.html))
3. Now you need to break your path into individual segments: Select the path, select the path tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>), and select all nodes (<kbd>ctrl-A</kbd>). With all nodes selected, click on the "Break path at selected nodes" button in the path edit toolbar.
4. Now you need to break your path (that contains several segments) into individual paths so you can color them. Do this with *Path -> Break Apart*.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! But cycle still is cycle. Is it possible to change lines to strict direct lines? Circle should be like a polyhedron.

Comment: @InkscapeQ - then use the Polygon tool instead of the Circle tool, and break that apart. Juancho's method works with any shape you want to start with. It's not limited to straight lines and circles.

Comment: @InkscapeQ You could also select all the nodes of the circle, then hit the "Make Selected Nodes Corner" button twice.  That will remove all the curves.

Comment: You may need to convert the circle to a path before you add nodes.